# Style the default @screen size with custom classes

Tags: tailwind-css

How can I add style for the default screen size, something like this:

```
@screen lg {
  .class {
    height: 1rem;
  }
}
```

but for the ["default size"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XIvlz.png).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All classes without prefix `sm:`, `md:`, `lg:`, `xl:` are a default screen size.

Comment: I know that, but in the css file, without using classes in the html, how can I do this?

Comment: @Weebonn just use pure the CSS, because this don't has nothing to do with Tailwind CSS. But you may use Tailwind CSS classes via `@apply` directives, for example: `.custom-class { @apply bg-red-500; }` in you `.css` file.